# DNN Persona Bar module routing

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I am trying to create dnn persona bar module for dnn9, 
Front-end part sends request to the url like - http://dnndev.me/API/personaBar/ControllerName/ActionName
and I get error - 
Unable to locate a controller for http://dnndev.me/API/personaBar/ControllerName/ActionName 
 Searched in namespaces: Dnn.PersonaBar.AdminLogs.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.ConfigConsole.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.CssEditor.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Extensions.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Licensing.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Pages.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Recyclebin.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Roles.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Security.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Seo.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Servers.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.SiteImportExport.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Sites.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.SiteSettings.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.SqlConsole.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.TaskScheduler.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.UI.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Users.Services, Dnn.PersonaBar.Vocabularies.Services.

the question is how to add my namespace to this list to
register custom api controller derived from DnnApiController ?

For SPA module it's simple with ServiceRouteMapper, is it posible for DNN persona bar module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a PersonaBar extension, your webapi service controllers should inherit from PersonaBarApiController.

```
[MenuPermission(MenuName = "Dnn.Users")]
public class UsersController : PersonaBarApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateUser(CreateUserContract contract)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your dnn manifest should look something like this to install as PersonaBar menu extension:

```
<package name="Dnn.PersonaBar.Users" type="PersonaBar" version="01.06.00">
...
    <component type="PersonaBarMenu">
          <menu>
            <identifier>Dnn.Users</identifier>
            <moduleName>Users</moduleName>
            <controller>Dnn.PersonaBar.Users.Components.UsersMenuController, Dnn.PersonaBar.Users</controller>
            <resourceKey>nav_Users</resourceKey>
            <path>Users</path>
            <parent>Manage</parent>
            <order>10</order>
            <defaultPermissions>Administrators</defaultPermissions>
          </menu>
    </component>
...
</package>
```

This results in endpoint path: /API/PersonaBar/Users/CreateUser

Full example source code [here](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.AdminExperience.Extensions/tree/development/src/Modules/Manage/Dnn.PersonaBar.Users)

Comment: I derived my api controller from PersonaBarApiController as you suggested and got the same error.
seems it is not enough to just inherit from PersonaBarApiController, should
I have  in .dnn manifest package type="Module" ? or type="PersonaBar" should be enough?

Comment: I revised my answer with more detail.